# How to save arbitrarily-structured documents with Java DynamoDBMapper class

Tags: java, json, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using Amazon's DynamoDBMapper Java class to save data to a DynamoDB table. This code needs to work for data structured in multiple different ways, so I would like to stay away from writing particularly structure-specific code. For this reason, I store the code as JSON objects in Java -- which are basically glorified HashMaps.

I would like to store these JSON objects into DynamoDB as [Dynamo's relatively new JSON Document type](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-update-json-and-more/).

The way the DynamoDBMapper API works is essentially that you write a Java class (typically a POJO), then add some annotations, then pass your objects of that class into DynamoDBMapper so that it can then put items into the database with the structure of the Java class. This works well for many aspects of what I'm doing, but not with the fact that I want these classes to contain arbitrarily-structured JSON documents. [This is the way you're meant to store JSON documents using DynamoDBMapper](https://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx21AOIBXRCAMFX/Storing-JSON-documents-in-Amazon-DynamoDB-tables), and as you can see, it doesn't allow for the structure of the documents to be arbitrary.

I realize I could use Dynamo's putItem() to pass the jsons as Strings into Item objects -- I just wanted to see if what I want to do is possible with DynamoDBMapper before I shift my approach.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using the DynamoDB Java document SDK instead of the object mapper. This allows you to serialize and deserialize JSON strings using the fromJSON and toJSON methods in the Item class. Check out http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaDocumentAPIItemCRUD.html.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I came up with my answer of how to store arbitrary Map objects in DynamoDB. This is extremely useful for archiving REST API responses that have been unmarshaled to foreign objects. I'm personally using this to archive REST responses from the PayPal Payment API. I don't care what variables they use in their REST API or the structure of their POJO / beans. I just want to make sure I save everything.

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "PaymentResponse")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = PayPalPaymentResponse.class, name = "PayPalPaymentResponse"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = BatchPayPalPaymentResponse.class, name = "BatchPayPalPaymentResponse")}
    )
public abstract class PaymentResponse {

    // store any arbitrary REST resrponse data in map form so we don't have to worry about the 
    // structure or the actual response itself
    protected Map<String, String> paymentResponseData = Maps.newHashMap();

    public PaymentResponse(PaymentResponseType paymentResponseType) {
        this.paymentResponseType = paymentResponseType;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getPaymentResponseData() { return paymentResponseData; }

    public void setPaymentResponseData(Map<String, String> paymentResponseData) { this.paymentResponseData = paymentResponseData; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(paymentResponseData.entrySet().toArray());
    }
}

public class ConverterUtils {

      public static BatchPayPalPaymentResponse getBatchPayPalPaymentResponse(PayoutBatch payoutBatch) throws IOException {
        //read in the PayoutBatch response data and convert it first to a JSON string and then convert the
        //JSON string into a Map<String, String>
        Map<String, String> responseData = objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(payoutBatch), new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {});
        BatchPayPalPaymentResponse batchPayPalPaymentResponse = new BatchPayPalPaymentResponse(responseData);
        return batchPayPalPaymentResponse;
    }

    public static PayPalPaymentResponse getSinglePayPalPaymentResponse(PayoutItemDetails payoutItemDetails) throws IOException {
        //read in the paypal PayoutItemDetails response data and convert it first to a JSON string and then convert the
        //JSON string into a Map<String, String>
        Map<String, String> responseData = objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(payoutItemDetails), new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {});
        PayPalPaymentResponse payPalPaymentResponse = new PayPalPaymentResponse(responseData);
        return payPalPaymentResponse;

    }
}

public class BatchPayPalPaymentResponse extends PaymentResponse {
    public BatchPayPalPaymentResponse(Map<String, String> responseData) {
        super(responseData);
    }
    ....
    ....
    ....
}

public class PayPalPaymentResponse extends PaymentResponse {
    public PayPalPaymentResponse(Map<String, String> responseData) {
        super(responseData);
    }
    ....
    ....
    ....
}
```

Now you can just call `mapper.save(instanceOfPaymentResponse)`. Note that my code also includes how to use a Jackson parser to pick and choose which sub-class of `PaymentResponse` to unmarshal too. That's because I use a `DynamoDBTypeConverter` to marshal my class to a string before putting it into the database.

Finally, I'll throw in my converter for completeness so it all hopefully makes sense.

```
public class PaymentResponseConverter implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<String, PaymentResponse> {

    private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    static {
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    }

    @Override
    public String convert(PaymentResponse object) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Received invalid instance of PaymentResponse and cannot marshal it to a string (%s)", e.getMessage()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public PaymentResponse unconvert(String object) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(object, PaymentResponse.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Unable to convert JSON to instance of PaymentResponse. This is a fatal error. (%s)", e.getMessage()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and went the route of serializing and deserializing  objects to json string by myself and then just store them as strings. The whole Document concept of DynamoDB is IMHO just a glorified object serializer. Only if you need to access attributes inside your object in dynamodb actions (eg. scans, projections) it makes sense to use the json document type. If our data is opaque to dynamodb, you are better off with strings.